# Using NSUndoManager inside a block

Tags: objective-c, macos, nsundomanager

Im trying to add some undo/redo to a block code (importing some files from NSOpenPanel) and as long as the code originates from the block the main code will work but the NSUndoManager code will not save and does not give any errors. The NSUndoManager code works anywhere else as long as its not in the block

The example NSUndoManager code would be the following:

```
// Undo Work
id  undoObject = [NSApp targetForAction:@selector(undoManager) to:nil from:self];
NSUndoManager *undoManager = [undoObject undoManager];
[[undoManager prepareWithInvocationTarget:self] deleteImages];
[undoManager setActionName:@"import images"];
```

The following shows where the code does and doesn't work:

```
/* NSUndoManager code works */ 
NSOpenPanel *openPanel = [NSOpenPanel openPanel];
[openPanel beginSheetModalForWindow:[self.windowController window]
                  completionHandler:^(NSInteger result) {
                      if (result == NSFileHandlingPanelOKButton) {
                          /* NSUndoManager code does not work, 
                             it also does not work inside importImages: */
                          [self importImages:[openPanel URLs]];
                      } else {
                          [openPanel close];
                      }
                  }];
/* NSUndoManager code works */
```

Comment: Im not being sarcastic here, could you explain what "works" means a little more specifically?  Also you left out the undomanager code from the block that didnt work.  Its hard to tell if your trying to use an instance that you create previously or if you call [undoManager undoManager] inside the block (which you should)  Factory methods are intended to be used as such and there's not much point in keeping default instances around in variables except for small invocations where it improves code clarity.

Answer (score 0):

The block is on the stack, so when the undo action will get called, probably the undo manager object will be already deallocated (or if not so, set to nil).So ensure that the undo manager will be alive, declaring is as class instance, or using the __block syntax (without ARC):

```
__block NSUndoManager* undoManager;
NSOpenPanel *openPanel = [NSOpenPanel openPanel];
[openPanel beginSheetModalForWindow:[self.windowController window]
                  completionHandler:^(NSInteger result) {
                      if (result == NSFileHandlingPanelOKButton) {
                          id  undoObject = [NSApp targetForAction:@selector(undoManager) to:nil from:self];
                          undoManager=[undoObject undoManager];
                          [[undoManager prepareWithInvocationTarget:self] deleteImages];
                          [undoManager setActionName:@"import images"];
                          [self importImages:[openPanel URLs]];
                      } else {
                          [openPanel close];
                      }
                  }];
```

When you have finished with the undo manager, you can set it to nil.

Comment: The pointer to undo manager is not going to change regardless whether its accessed inside a block or not.  __block would have no affect in this case.  And if it did resetting the value of undo manager from inside the block would be dangerous, you would be screwing up the value of the pointer on someone elses stack.  Again that pointer doesnt change ever and __block is only for when you want to *modify* a stack allocated value, not simply read it and call methods on it.